# Store Table Row As Object(?) Using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm keeping my code D.R.Y. and want to save the first instance variable below (`@most_recent_game_tr`) so I can call it later as `SomeObject` and get its `td:nth-child(x).text`. Which (not necessarily) Nokogiri method(s) might you use to accomplish this?

```
@most_recent_game_tr = doc.css("#games tbody tr:nth-child(#{game_played})")

@result = doc.css("#games tbody tr:nth-child(#{game_played}) td:nth-child(6)").text
@opponent_name = doc.css("#games tbody tr:nth-child(#{game_played}) td:nth-child(5)").text
@rangers = doc.css("#games tbody tr:nth-child(#{game_played}) td:nth-child(8)").text
@extra_time = doc.css("#games tbody tr:nth-child(#{game_played}) td:nth-child(7)").text
@opponent = doc.css("#games tbody tr:nth-child(#{game_played}) td:nth-child(9)").text
@date_result = Date.parse(doc.css("#games tbody tr:nth-child(#{game_played}) td:nth-child(2)").text)
@date = Date.parse(doc.css("#games tbody tr:nth-child(#{game_played + 1}) td:nth-child(2)").text)
```

Comment: It's difficult to say what is the best way since you didn't show us what the original HTML looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve like this

`@most_recent_game_tr = doc.css("#games tbody tr:nth-child(#{game_played})")`

`@result = @most_recent_game_tr.at_css("td:nth-child(6)").text`